# Keep rows with less than two secquential capital letters (pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that contains names, but some of them are in capital letters, like:

```
d = {'col1': ['MICHAEL', 'Sabrina', 'BEn', 'Jay-Lynn'], 'col2': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I only want to keep the rows that have the correct way to spell a name, so with only one sequential capital letter. In this case I want to keep only Sabrina and Jay-Lynn. I want to keep the other names in a seperate dataframe.

I have all my other code in pandas, mostly with str.contains() so it would be nice to have this one in pandas too.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, use `pandas.Series.str.istitle`:

```
df2 = df[df["col1"].str.istitle()]
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
       col1 col2
1   Sabrina    2
3  Jay-Lynn    4
```